# How do I get the AWS Amplify CLI to work?

Tags: aws-amplify-cli

I can't get `amplify add auth` to work as described. I get stuck at the "Enter a name for your identity pool" step. No matter what I enter it is not accepted and I get "The name of the identity pool should be between 1 and 128 characters."

Even simply hitting return and accepting the default value fails.

Does the CLI work? If so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying as a pool name? You're aware that some chars can't be used?

Comment: @0stone0 I've tried everything. Right down to "abcdefg" and "sdjfhkeUhabqirbq" as well as the default value offered which consists of just letters, numbers, and underscores.

Comment: Mm are you sure it's `amplify add auth` and not `amplify auth add`?

Comment: @0stone0 I tried both. (And incidentally, what's with that; are they different commands, why are they two that look so similar?

Comment: Not quite sure, not that familiar with aws-amplify-cli. Found [this git page](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/master/packages/amplify-category-auth/Readme.md) that indicates `amplify auth add` as the correct command.